# Handling Let's encrypt new certificates in WebView for Android M and older

Tags: android, webview, android-webview, lets-encrypt

Android apps, running on devices with Android M or older, using WebView to display web content may experience breakages from Jan 2021 as Let's Encrypt will start issuing certificates signed with their new certificate chain in 2021

Read https://letsencrypt.org/2020/11/06/own-two-feet.html for background.

Answer (score 3):

First, to know if you app will have an issue, try to open https://valid-isrgrootx1.letsencrypt.org/ on Android devices with M and older.

The solution for WebViews has two parts:

**API >= 24**

Add the Let's [Encrypt root certificates (X1 and X2)](https://letsencrypt.org/certificates/) to the `network_security_config.xml` file.

```
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" >
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="@raw/isrg_root_x1" />
            <certificates src="@raw/isrg_root_x2" />
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Then add the network security config to your Android manifest

```
<manifest...>
  <application
      ...
      android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
      ...
  </application>
</manifest>
```

**API < 24**

For older devices Android does not have public API to add certificates to its trust manager and so the validation will have to be done manually.

- override `onReceivedSslError` in your WebView client
- upon `SSL_UNTRUSTED` error perform a chan validation manually

```kotlin
    override fun onReceivedSslError(view: WebView?, handler: SslErrorHandler, error: SslError) {
        var trusted = false
        when (error.primaryError) {
            SSL_UNTRUSTED -> {
                // manual validation
                trusted = validateSslCertificateChain(error.certificate)
            }
            else -> ...
        }

        if (trusted) handler.proceed() else super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error)
    }
```

The function `validateSslCertificateChain` is the one that will manually perform the chain validation. It can be done in several ways. An example can be found in [this PR for DuckDuckGo browser](https://github.com/duckduckgo/Android/pull/1035).

Also see [this other SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64844311/certpathvalidatorexception-connecting-to-a-lets-encrypt-host-on-android-m-or-ea/65303942#65303942) for solutions in other Android networking areas.

Comment: Optional you can also check the version in the _onReceivedSslError_ to call super method if above 24 since this is catched by the network config file.

Comment: You can do that, but it does not really change anything. onReceivedSslError is only called below API 24. So that version check in onReceivedSslError would do nothing actually

Comment: Thank you for that info

Comment: I'm unable to add @raw/isrg_root_x1 and @raw/isrg_root_x2 folders in my projecto in Android Studio. Some how don't how them when I add them...

Comment: @RodasPT you can check this link : https://www.danieldent.com/blog/android-apps-lets-encrypt-dst-root-expiry/

Comment: @AitorViana  do you have example of use of "validateSslCertificateChain " function?