# Make app on Android < 7.1.1 trust Let's Encrypt ISRG Root X1

Tags: android, ssl, okhttp, lets-encrypt

I have an app which is developed using react-native.

Starting from the 11th January 2011, Android devices running 7.1.1 and below will stop trusting the Let's Encrypt certificate which I am using on my servers (according to [this](https://letsencrypt.org/2020/11/06/own-two-feet.html))

How can I make my app trust my server's certificate (ISRG Root X1)?

Comment: Related/Dup: [CertPathValidatorException connecting to a Let's Encrypt host on Android M or earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64844311/295004)

Comment: I really don't understand what I should do. I am not familiar with Java. I need some more specific explanation on which file I need to alter.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you can combine two answers

1. How to workaround the issue from the [SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64844311/295004) in the comments
2. How to configure OkHttp in React Native, a similar example is [here](https://medium.com/@jaedmuva/react-native-ssl-pinning-is-back-e317e6682642)

But you should discuss with your security team if you have one and follow guidance from Let's Encrypt here.