# Android devices <API 25 not connecting to LetsEncrypt SSL servers anymore?

Tags: android, https, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt

Since the last 3-monthly renewal of my **Let's Encrypt** certificate (happened 3 days ago), **Android devices** with OS version earlier than 7.1.1 (**Android API < 25**), are not able to connect to my servers anymore.

The reason seems to be that the 3-year cross-sign agreement to bridge the new *Let's Encrypt*'s "**ISRG Root X1**" certificate via the old partner *IdenTrust*'s "**DST Root CA X3**" certificate has expired earlier this year (2024), as reported here:
https://letsencrypt.org/2020/12/21/extending-android-compatibility

What is the best solution to allow the earlier Android devices to keep  working with LetsEncrypt SSL servers?

Comment: Following to the forum link in the link provided: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/old-android-tablets-cant-connect-to-le-certs-anymore/213707/13

Comment: Is this question about an Android app using your web site or just your website in a web browser on Android?

Comment: @Robert Android app

Comment: A prior analysis and sample code for OkHttp is here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64844311/certpathvalidatorexception-connecting-to-a-lets-encrypt-host-on-android-m-or-ea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is still possible to use the cross-sign mechanism until **6th June 2024**, with certificates being valid for extra 90 days (so, up to the *beginning of September 2024*), as explained here:
https://letsencrypt.org/2023/07/10/cross-sign-expiration

You can do that, by specifying the following option in the **certbot** renewal command:

`--preferred-chain "DST Root CA X3"`

as described here: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/old-android-tablets-cant-connect-to-le-certs-anymore/213707/2