Android 7 and below SSL compatibility
Recently I renewed my Let's Encrypt SSL certificate and the Android version 7 and below devices started to show network error problems. Other devices that have SO above version 7 are still working.
I decided to change to zerossl because I read in a blog that these problems don't exist with zerossl certificates. With this option any request of devices are blocked. Even with SO number above 7.
Other option was renew the Let's Encrypt SSL certificate with DST Root CA X3 parameter, but this certificate will be expired this year.
Which option or service can I choose to avoid dropping support for Android 7 or lower because of SSL incompatibility?

The compatibility list for ZeroSSL says that it should be supported. If it does not even work with newer devices than you likely have a server side configuration problem instead, for example failure to include the intermediate certificates. Check your site with SSLLabs.

Let's encrypt already creates by default certificates that fail on Android 7 and before, thus in most cases connections will fail long before cross signjng end date is reached. The most easiest way for Android 6 and 7 would be to include the missing root CA certificate in the app and enable it using a network security configuration file. And Android 5 and below users will have to install the new Let's Encrypt toot CA in their systems anyway as otherwise half of the web will stop working.

@SteffenUllrich how could it be a server side configuration issue if when I changed the ssl the expected behaviour return to work? it's a honest question, I'm newbie at this subject

@KaioBorges: server side configuration in this case means how your certificates are configured at the server (you switched from Let's Encrypt to ZerosSSL). There are various parts to a proper configuration: leaf certificate, chain certificates, private key. A common problem is that one omits the chain certificates or uses the ones from the previous certificate when configuring a new certificate.

@SteffenUllrich I understood, thx. I got the files from ZeroSSL website and changed the LE config paths at nginx config file to the new folder with ZeroSSL files, chain and privkey, is there anything in this steps that I missed?

@KaioBorges: This description is too imprecise to understand what exactly you did. Again, I recommend that you check your site with SSLLabs.

See https://stackoverflow.com/q/64844311

No enough information regarding blocked requests. I would expect it's the issue with your configuration.
General answer is:
To maintain Android 7 compatibility you have to use certificate from an issuer who uses a valid trusted root already installed on the device. Let's Encrypt is not the go to solution for older device anymore. Look for other options: https://acmeclients.com/certificate-authorities/
Alternatively you can go with a paid certificate solution. If you control the used application, or even a hardware you can handle the certificate trust on your own.
